# Using getline in C++ to get the contain (integers) from a file and input them into array to be used as input of a C++ fft program

Tags: c++, arrays, text-files, getline

I'm using getline to get input from a file (myfile.txt)from my computer, the file contains following values : 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0.
Each of these values will be put into an array x[n] which will be used later as input of my fast fourier transform program.
however,when I am running the program,the output is a bit different from the original program ie. the one which the array has values declared directly inside the program (  const Complex test[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };)

```
    //original code
    #include <complex>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <valarray>

    const double PI = 3.141592653589793238460;

    typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
    typedef std::valarray<Complex> CArray;

    // Cooley–Tukey FFT (in-place, divide-and-conquer)
    // Higher memory requirements and redundancy although more intuitive
    void fft(CArray& x)
    {
        const size_t N = x.size();
        if (N <= 1) return;

        // divide
        CArray even = x[std::slice(0, N/2, 2)];
        CArray  odd = x[std::slice(1, N/2, 2)];

        // conquer
        fft(even);
        fft(odd);

        // combine
        for (size_t k = 0; k < N/2; ++k)
        {
            Complex t = std::polar(1.0, -2 * PI * k / N) * odd[k];
            x[k    ] = even[k] + t;
            x[k+N/2] = even[k] - t;
        }
    }

    // Cooley-Tukey FFT (in-place, breadth-first, decimation-in-frequency)
    // Better optimized but less intuitive
    void fft(CArray &x)
    {
        // DFT
        unsigned int N = x.size(), k = N, n;
        double thetaT = 3.14159265358979323846264338328L / N;
        Complex phiT = Complex(cos(thetaT), sin(thetaT)), T;
        while (k > 1)
        {
            n = k;
            k >>= 1;
            phiT = phiT * phiT;
            T = 1.0L;
            for (unsigned int l = 0; l < k; l++)
            {
                for (unsigned int a = l; a < N; a += n)
                {
                    unsigned int b = a + k;
                    Complex t = x[a] - x[b];
                    x[a] += x[b];
                    x[b] = t * T;
                }
                T *= phiT;
            }
        }
        // Decimate
        unsigned int m = (unsigned int)log2(N);
        for (unsigned int a = 0; a < N; a++)
        {
            unsigned int b = a;
            // Reverse bits
            b = (((b & 0xaaaaaaaa) >> 1) | ((b & 0x55555555) << 1));
            b = (((b & 0xcccccccc) >> 2) | ((b & 0x33333333) << 2));
            b = (((b & 0xf0f0f0f0) >> 4) | ((b & 0x0f0f0f0f) << 4));
            b = (((b & 0xff00ff00) >> 8) | ((b & 0x00ff00ff) << 8));
            b = ((b >> 16) | (b << 16)) >> (32 - m);
            if (b > a)
            {
                Complex t = x[a];
                x[a] = x[b];
                x[b] = t;
            }
        }
        //// Normalize (This section make it not working correctly)
        //Complex f = 1.0 / sqrt(N);
        //for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        //  x[i] *= f;
    }

    // inverse fft (in-place)
    void ifft(CArray& x)
    {
        // conjugate the complex numbers
        x = x.apply(std::conj);

        // forward fft
        fft( x );

        // conjugate the complex numbers again
        x = x.apply(std::conj);

        // scale the numbers
        x /= x.size();
    }

    int main()
    {
        const Complex test[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
        CArray data(test, 8);

        // forward fft
        fft(data);`enter code here`

        std::cout << "fft" << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
        }

        // inverse fft
        ifft(data);

        std::cout << std::endl << "ifft" << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }`  

//new modified code
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std; 
const double PI = 3.141592653589793238460;

typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
typedef std::valarray<Complex> CArray;
// Cooley–Tukey FFT (in-place, divide-and-conquer)
// Higher memory requirements and redundancy although more intuitive
void fft(CArray& x)
{
    const size_t N = x.size();
    if (N <= 1) return;

    // divide
    CArray even = x[std::slice(0, N/2, 2)];
    CArray  odd = x[std::slice(1, N/2, 2)];

    // conquer
    fft(even);
    fft(odd);

    // combine
    for (size_t k = 0; k < N/2; ++k)
    {
        Complex t = std::polar(1.0, -2 * PI * k / N) * odd[k];
        x[k    ] = even[k] + t;
        x[k+N/2] = even[k] - t;
    }
}

// Cooley-Tukey FFT (in-place, breadth-first, decimation-in-frequency)
// Better optimized but less intuitive
/*
void fft(CArray &x)
{
    // DFT
    unsigned int N = x.size(), k = N, n;
    double thetaT = 3.14159265358979323846264338328L / N;
    Complex phiT = Complex(cos(thetaT), sin(thetaT)), T;
    while (k > 1)
    {
        n = k;
        k >>= 1;
        phiT = phiT * phiT;
        T = 1.0L;
        for (unsigned int l = 0; l < k; l++)
        {
            for (unsigned int a = l; a < N; a += n)
            {
                unsigned int b = a + k;
                Complex t = x[a] - x[b];
                x[a] += x[b];
                x[b] = t * T;
            }
            T *= phiT;
        }
    }
    // Decimate
    unsigned int m = (unsigned int)log2(N);
    for (unsigned int a = 0; a < N; a++)
    {
        unsigned int b = a;
        // Reverse bits
        b = (((b & 0xaaaaaaaa) >> 1) | ((b & 0x55555555) << 1));
        b = (((b & 0xcccccccc) >> 2) | ((b & 0x33333333) << 2));
        b = (((b & 0xf0f0f0f0) >> 4) | ((b & 0x0f0f0f0f) << 4));
        b = (((b & 0xff00ff00) >> 8) | ((b & 0x00ff00ff) << 8));
        b = ((b >> 16) | (b << 16)) >> (32 - m);
        if (b > a)
        {
            Complex t = x[a];
            x[a] = x[b];
            x[b] = t;
        }
    }

} */
// inverse fft (in-place)
void ifft(CArray& x)

{
    // conjugate the complex numbers
    x = x.apply(std::conj);

    // forward fft
    fft( x );

    // conjugate the complex numbers again
    x = x.apply(std::conj);

    // scale the numbers
    x /= x.size();
}

int main()

{   

    int n=0;
    int b=0;
    int q=0;
    int i;
    int Nx=0;
    //double *x;
        double x [8];
    /**************************************************** getting x ********************************************/

        string line;
        double Result;
             ifstream myfile ("myfile.txt");
             if (myfile.is_open())
               {
                 for ( i = 0 ; (i < 8) && (myfile >> x[i]) ; ++i) 

            cout << line << '\n';
                 stringstream convert(line);

                 if ( !(convert >> Result) )
                Result = 0;

                 x[i]=Result;

               }
            else cout << "Unable to open file";
    /****************************************************************************************************************/


    Complex test[8];     
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 8 ; ++i )
    test[i] = x[i];

    CArray data(test, 8);

    // forward fft
    fft(data);

    std::cout << "fft" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        cout << data[i] << endl;
    }

    // inverse fft
    ifft(data);

    std::cout << std::endl << "ifft" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}



The purpose of this task is to calculate the FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) of an input se
```

quence

Comment: You can (and should) edit your question instead of commenting in order to clarify it. But, more important, take the time to read the site guidelines. In particular, your question is considered off-topic, because you didn't reduce your problem to a minimal but complete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are (at least) three points to correct in your modified code.

(1) You use `16` where (if I'm not wrong) you should use `8`; `x` should be `new double[8]` (or `double x[8]`? why do you use a dynamic array?); `test` should be `Complex test[8];`, `CArray data(test, 16);` should be `CArray data(test, 8);`

(2) you don't initialize `i` in the reading file loop; so when you write

```
x[i]=(double)Result;
```

the value of `i` is undefined. So, if `i` is in the range [0,16[, you lose the first 7 values and the 8th value is in `x[i]`; the other values of `x` are undefined. If `i` is out of the range [0,16[, the program can crash.

En passant: `x[i]` and `Result` are `double`; so the cast is superflous.

I suppose your cycle should be (remembering you have only 8 values) something like

```
  for ( i = 0 ; (i < 8) && getline(myfile, line) ; ++i )
   {
     cout << line << '\n';
     stringstream convert(line);

     if ( !(convert >> Result) )
        Result = 0;

     x[i]=Result;
   }
```

(3) I don't understand what should be

```
const Complex test[16] = x[i];
```

I suppose your intention was

```
Complex test[8];     
for ( i = 0 ; i < 8 ; ++i )
   test[i] = x[i];
```

**---- EDIT ----**

Correction: a correct way to load the file can be

```
//   double Result;
ifstream myfile ("myfile.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
 {
   for ( i = 0 ; (i < 8) && (myfile >> x[i]) ; ++i 
    ;

   // no need for myfile.close() (take care of it the destructor)
 }
else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

Sorry.

Comment: Hi Max, thank you for your recommendation, I modified the code as you suggested , however is still different from the original program, I have replaced the modified program by the new one, I have also past the new result.

Comment: @ Serge - it's my fault, sorry: corrected my answer

Comment: Max, it works now !!! ,thank you for your help, I have modified again my previous post with the correct code.  Who knows, someone may have the same problem as me today in the future